# Saving Excel file with EPPlus

Tags: vb.net, excel, performance, epplus

I recently updated my .NET application to use the EPPlus library for saving Excel files (was previously using MS COM interop library), and the performance is better (about 50% speed increase), but the actual call for saving the file is pretty slow (in some cases, slower than the save call when I was using MS COM interop).

The Excel workbook has about 1.2 million cells (about 20,000 rows, split between 32 worksheets, with an average of about 60 columns per sheet), and file size is about 6.2 MB.  After get data for the sheet, the process of creating and saving takes about 15-16 seconds.  This is about 4 seconds for creating the EPPlus ExcelPackage, about 1 second to do some formatting (cell comments, dropdowns, etc.), and then about 10 seconds for saving the file, to a location on my C: drive.

Is there any way to improve the performance of creating the ExcelPackage or saving the Excel file?

Here's the method for creating the ExcelPackage object:

```
Public Shared Function CreateExcelPackageFromDS(ByVal ds As DataSet) As ExcelPackage
    Dim xlPackage As New ExcelPackage()
    Dim oBook As ExcelWorkbook = xlPackage.Workbook

    'Load each table into worksheet
    For Each dt As System.Data.DataTable In ds.Tables
        Dim ws As ExcelWorksheet = oBook.Worksheets.Add(dt.TableName)
        ws.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(dt, True)
        ws.Cells.Style.Locked = False
    Next

    Return xlPackage
End Function
```

And here's the code for calling that method and saving Excel file:

```
CreateExcelPackage(ds)

'Formatting stuff goes here

Dim excelFile As New FileInfo(tempFilesPath & "\Export" & userID & ".xlsx")
xlPackage.SaveAs(excelFile)

'Stuff for writing Excel file to HTML Response goes here
```

I have tried other methods of saving the file, but they are either about equal (such as using ExcelPackage.SaveAs to a MemoryStream), or slower (using ExcelPackage.GetAsByteArray and using that in the Response).

Comment: Sounds like you are limited by the write speed of your HDD...

Comment: It is a limitation of the library I guess. http://epplus.codeplex.com/discussions/404208. You can ask the person on this discussion or run the tests yourself.

Comment: I am seeing similar performance with a 6MB xlsx with 3x sheets, 38 columns & around 90k lines in total, 30 seconds to build it and 20 seconds to write it. Using i7 quad, 32GB RAM, 1TB SSD so not much in the way of bottlenecks there.